# PetaPoco vs NPoco

Tags: c#, nuget, petapoco, npoco

`NPoco` seems to be a DLL that implments more advanced features of `PetaPoco`.  `PetaPoco` installs code generation templates and `PetaPoco.cs`.  The Nuget version of `PetaPoco` is 4.0.3.  I know there are versions (ie., 4.0.12) that implement some of the features in `NPoco`.

How do I use the code generation in `PetaPoco` and the latest features in `NPoco` together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use the PetaPoco code generation stuff with NPoco, however I have not tested it as I do not use/like it.

Most of the methods are the same, but you might have to tweak them slightly. You can just place the `TT` files into your project and run them as well as adding NPoco to your project.

If you do get them working, let me know and I may consider adding them back into NPoco. ;)

Comment: So far so good.  I replace PetaPoco in PetaPoco.Generator.ttinclude with NPoco.  And on line 149 of same, I changed autoIncrement to AutoIncrement.

Comment: I did make the tt file ugly in order to make Database.cs cute.  Funny sort of dual-space that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [this project's](https://github.com/Rhysling/NPoco.T4) T4 templates to generate classes backed by NPoco